# Sharing internet using Network-Over-USB in Raspberry Zero based on ( BeagleBone Black method)

Tags: linux, usb, internet

need to connect my pi via USB Ethernet to my WIFI PC (Linux Mint LMDE 3 Cindy) to connecting to the internet.
I have changed my pi IP to `192.168.7.2` by [this instruction](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98790/raspberry-pi-zero-internet-connection-through-usb-for-linux-os/98828#98828).
After that, I have done the instruction base of [this site](https://elementztechblog.wordpress.com/2014/12/22/sharing-internet-using-network-over-usb-in-beaglebone-black/) and [this](http://klaus.ede.hih.au.dk/index.php/BBB_Internet_over_the_USB_cable) which are for BBB in Linux MINT (Debian) and changed it for my PI by this way:

## PI console can be got by using the following command

```
ssh 192.168.7.2 -l pi
```

## In the PI console type the following

```
sudo ifconfig usb0 192.168.7.2
sudo route add default gw 192.168.7.1
```

## In the linux console of host system type

```
sudo su
#wlan0 is my internet facing interface, eth5 is the BeagleBone USB connection
ifconfig enp0s20f0u2 192.168.7.1
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface wlp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface enp0s20f0u2 -j ACCEPT
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Incase network not accessible then type the following in PI terminal

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

i gave problem switching my WiFi internet to Ethernet  which solved by [this instruction](https://askubuntu.com/questions/263572/can-i-use-wi-fi-and-cable-ethernet-networking-at-same-time).

Finally get answer from my pi console when i ping to my WiFi IP (`192.168.1.105`) based of `ifconfig` data, but i could not connect to internet

***Update***:

I have run this codes in my Laptop and its working:

```
# firstlu offing 
# Disable bridge interface
sudo ip link set br0 down
#wlp2s0 is my internet facing interface, enp0s20f0u2 is the Raspberry USB connection

sudo ifconfig enp0s20f0u2 192.168.7.1
sudo iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface wlp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface enp0s20f0u2 -j ACCEPT
sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
#and then in pc do this
sudo ip link set br0 up
```

I have this setting in my `/etc/network/interfaces` file :

```
so@notebook:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d


# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback


iface enp0s20f0u1 inet static
  adress 192.168.7.5
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 192.168.7.1
  gateway 192.168.1.1
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 

allow-hotplug wlp2s0
#iface wlp2s0 


#auto br0
#  bridge_ports wlp2s0 enp0s20f0u1
#  bridge_stp off
#  bridge_fd 0
#  bridge_maxwait 0
```

but i don't know why it must disable and enable br0 in my IP setting to it working?!!!
So what do you thinking?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is creating a bridge on your host so that your network configuration looks something like this:

```
     LAN (192.168.1.0/24)
------------------------------
               |
              br0
       +----------------+
       |   enp0s20f0u1  |
       |                |
       |     wlp2s0     |
       +----------------+
```

However, when you create the bridge, `wlp2s0` still owns your LAN address (`192.168.1.x` most likely). But `br0` must own that IP address to work, so by bringing it down then up, I'm guessing you are unwittingly forcing your network manager to re-assign your LAN address to the bridge.

If you want to know what is happening at a network level, you should use iproute2 (`ip [command]`) exclusively, instead of mixing `ifconfig`, `ip` and `/etc/interfaces` (the latter being a high level configuration file for you network manager which internally calls `ip` for you). [Here is a good wiki page to get started](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration#iproute2).
Then you should setup your /etc/network/interfaces so that your network manager does it all automatically, without you needing to run `ip` commands manually. Normally, your network manager would just configure `br0` with only `wlp2s0` when your Raspberry Pi is disconnected.